# Grails: Domain class property name conflicts with embedded class property name

Tags: grails, grails-2.5

```
class Person {
    String name
    Country bornInCountry

    static embedded = ['bornInCountry']
}

class Country {
    String name
}
```

How can I filter **Person** by **name**?
When I use **name** in query (eg. `Person.countByNameIsNotNull()`), **Person** is filtered by **bornInCountry.name** instead.

Generated sql with `loggingSql = true`:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        count(*) as y0_ 
    from
        person this_ 
    where
        this_.born_in_country_name is not null
```

Code is taken from [grails documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.3/ref/Domain%20Classes/embedded.html)
grails version: 2.5.3

Comment: It is strange and seems to be a bug in gorm. Can you create another attribute like age for person domain class and see the generated sql? If that turns out to be true then open an issue in grails github repo. It is a bug.

Comment: If names are not the same, everything works as expected.

Comment: Which version of grails are you using? Can you report the same issue on https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues

Comment: Sure. I'm using 2.5.3, but same thing happens 3.1.4.

Comment: have you reported this issue?

Comment: yes, here https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9846